# Lebesgue integral is finite but functions are unbounded in every interval

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The following is a question in my midterm exam.

Let $f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a seq. of Lebesgue integrable functions such that 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_n(x) dx =1
$$
and $\sup_n f_n$ is unbounded in every open interval. Find such a sequence of $f_n$'s.

I've tried to think along the lines that for every irrational number my functions are $0$. But I'm unable to proceed along this direction since I don't know how to manipulate the functions at rational numbers to meet the above criteria.

Comment: $\sup$ or $ess \sup$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum

Comment: @Antitheos: Sup only

Comment: Then there's no need for a sequence. A single function can satisfy the requirement. Just take a function whose integral over the reals is 1 and then modify it to map each rational p/q in lowest terms to q. If you need a sequence then set every term to this function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f_0$ be function unbounded in a neighborhood of $0$ with finite integral, e.g. $$f_0(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}} \chi_{[-1,1]}.$$ You may need to rescale to make sure it has integral $1$. If $\{r_n\}$ is an enumeration of the rationals (or any dense countable set) you can define $$f_n(x) = f_0(x-r_n)$$ so that $f_n$ has integral $1$ but is unbounded on every neighborhood of $r_n$.  What can you say about $\sup_n f_n$?

Comment: @yo having $f_0(0)=0$ will easily fix the issue without changing the value of the integral.

Comment: Nonnegative measurable functions are allowed to take the value $+\infty$ - that is the case with $f_0$.

Comment: @Umberto P: Very elegant. Thanks. I constructed the following functions.    $f_n(x)=e^{-|x|}/2 \forall x \in R\Q $ and $ f_n(x)=r_n \forall x \in Q $ where $r_n$ is an increasing sequence of rational numbers to $\infty$

Comment: You will need to enumerate the $\{r_n\}$ carefully to make sure that your $f_n$ is unbounded in every interval.

Comment: @Umberto Any enumeration will be suitable as for any given open interval, if you pick up a point in the interval, you can find a rational sequence  from the enumeration converging to that point.

Comment: You're right - I didn't think that through very carefully.

Answer (score 4):

Let $h(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp{(-x^2)}$. I pick this because $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x)dx = 1.$

Let $g_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} \\ 
n & \mbox{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases} $

Let $f_n := g_n + h$

This works as $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and has Lebesgue measure $0$, so $f_n$ is lebesgue integrable $ \forall n \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_n(x)dx = 1 $, and $\sup_n f_n = \infty$ in every open interval.

Comment: Thanks. The essential idea is to use the denseness of rationals and perturb them at rationals by aribtrary amount to make sup unbounded but still the integral being same

Answer (score 3):

Pushing all the way to the extreme, just a single function can do all the job: Let $g_i(x)$ by

$$ g_i(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \mathbf{1}_{(0, 4^{-i})}(x). $$

Notice that $g_i$ is unbounded on any neighborhood of $0$ and its integral over $\Bbb{R}$ is $2^{-i}$. Now enumerate $\Bbb{Q}$ as $\{r_1, r_2, \cdots\}$ and define $f$ by

$$ f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} g_i(x - r_i). $$

Applying the monotone convergence theorem, this function is non-negative, integrable with $\int_{\Bbb{R}} f = 1$, and unbounded near any rational number. Consequntly this function is unbounded on any open interval.

Finally, take $(f_n) = (f, f, f, \cdots)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $q_1,q_2, \dots$ be the rationals. Define $f(x) = \chi_{(0,1)} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}n\chi_{\{q_n\}}.$ The sequence $f,f,f,\dots $ then does the job.